# How Can I Remove Child of A node list?

Tags: java, android, xml, list

I'am new in java and android. I have an XML file Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SendList>
   <listdata>
       <name>aaaaaa</name>
       <message>xfhjj</message>
       <tel>1111222</tel>
       <icon>list</icon>
   </listdata>
   <listdata>
       <name>bbbbbbbbb</name>
       <message>ghjchjxff</message>
       <tel>45885367</tel>
       <icon>list</icon>
   </listdata>
   <listdata>
       <name>ccccccc</name>
       <message>hkggcckj</message>
       <tel>46964788</tel>
       <icon>list</icon>
   </listdata>
</SendList>
```

I want to delete each of node  but with this code i use I receive Null pointer Exception except last Node !

```
                        Node no = document.getFirstChild();
                        NodeList nl = no.getChildNodes();
                        for (int n = 0; n < nl.getLength(); n++) {
                            Node list = document.getElementsByTagName("listdata").item(n);
                            NodeList nodes = list.getChildNodes();
                            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                                Node element = nodes.item(i);
                                String t = element.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                                if (deleteValueName.equals(t)) {  \\deleteValueName for example equal aaaaaa OR bbbbbbbbb
                                    if ("name".equals(element.getNodeName())) {
                                        Node nd = element.getParentNode();
                                        Node ndParent = nd.getParentNode();
                                        ndParent.removeChild(nd);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Please Help Me !

Comment: at what line is the NPE?

Comment: In Line "NodeList nodes = list.getChildNodes();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the 'document.getElementsByTagName' out of the for loop, because after each loop you have less and less elements, so you will eventually get a NPE. Try something like this:

```
NodeList nl = document.getElementsByTagName("listdata");
for (int n = 0; n < nl.getLength(); n++) {
    Node list = nl.item(n);
    NodeList nodes = list.getChildNodes();
    ...
```